# How do we run php artisan serve on ec2 to point to the elastic ip

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

Hi everyone I've been googling for more than 4 hours now ,but i still don't find what I really need,when i am on my localhost i am used on typing php artisan serve ON MY COMMAND LINE and the message Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8890/ is shown ,so now I am trying to use ssh to do the same thing but from my surprise it always show the same message like when i am on my localhost("Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8890/").I was expecting something like

```
Laravel development server started on http://myElasticIp:8890/
```

but it doesn't .Anyone who also have alternative methods to solve this problem is welcomed .Thank you in advance.

MY .htaccess file

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /laravel/public/
 # change above to your site i.e.,  RewriteBase /whatever/public/

 # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

 # Handle Front Controller...
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

My vhost

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
  <Directory "/var/www/html/kidio/mergeogle/laravel/public">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all 
  Require all granted 
  Allow from all
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80` will do the trick, but you should **never** use `php artisan serve` for production. A proper webserver like nginx/Apache is necessary for production use - the Laravel docs have configuration examples for both.

Comment: I am now getting this Failed to listen on 52.28.184.10:8890 (reason: Cannot assign requested address)

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed You likely have an existing webserver like Apache or nginx on port 80, then.

Comment: yes i do so does mean i won't be able to run the command u just showed me?or is the another way

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed If you have a webserver already installed, you should be using it to serve Laravel. There's no sense running the development server in that situation.

Comment: ok i see i got the first page working but the links the don't work ,it seems like my routes they are not recognised or somethig

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed Did you follow the instructions in the documentation for setting up Apache/nginx for Laravel's routes? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation#configuration

Comment: i just added my .htaccess